# In the following form how could I increase the length of input holder so that my form looks dense?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

```html
<div formGroupName="xxxx" class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <mat-form-field class="row-styling">
      <mat-label> Cell Phone </mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        phoneNumberOnly
        [value]="f.xxx['controls'].cellPhone.value | phone"
        (blur)="validatePhone($event.target)"
        maxlength="12"
        formControlName="cellPhone"
        name="yyy"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I have tried using style="width: 200px; in the platform field but it does not worked.https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUxmk.png

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codpen.io](https://codpen.io) for us.

Comment: Try to add the keyword important to your field maybe bootstrap is overriding your style like so. style="width: 200px!important;"

Comment: Tq @Friday Amesh it works

Comment: @teja, Kindly check the answer so that others will know your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already added the class named **row-styling** you just have to add the following lines of code in your .scss file and it should work.

```
.row-styling {
    input {
       width:200px;
    }
 }
```

if still you doesn't get the desired width you can add **!important** after 200px in .scss file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the phrase `important` to the style in your input control. Bootstrap style must be overriding your style like so.

```
<div formGroupName="xxxx" class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
            <mat-form-field class = "row-styling">
              <mat-label> Cell Phone </mat-label>
              <input style="width: 200px!important;" matInput phoneNumberOnly 
                [value]="f.xxx['controls'].cellPhone.value | phone"  
                (blur)="validatePhone($event.target)" 
                maxlength="12" formControlName="cellPhone" name="yyy" />
              </mat-form-field>
           </div>
    <div>
```